# Can't concatenate play.twirl.api.Html objects with play 2.3

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, twirl

I am trying to migrate a rather large project from play framework 2.2 to 2.3. In the project we have some helpers that do something like this:

```
import play.api.templates.Html;
...
private object HtmlHelper {
  ...
  // Given a sequence of Htmls, return a single Html containing them
  def html(htmls: Seq[Html]): Html = htmls.foldLeft(Html(""))(_+=_)
}
```

I have converted it to this:

```
import play.twirl.api.Html;
...
private object HtmlHelper {
  ...
  // Given a sequence of Htmls, return a single Html containing them
  def html(htmls: Seq[Html]): Html = htmls.foldLeft(Html(""))((r,c) => r + c)
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
Read from stdout: <PATH> type mismatch;
Read from stdout: found   : play.twirl.api.Html
Read from stdout: required: String
```

I've been trying to find documentation on this Html object in 2.3 but have had no luck finding anything. As far as I can see, the Html object implements Appendable, which means the + operator should work... I don't have time to learn all of Scala and this supposed "expressive" syntax is getting on my nerves.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more `+=` method defined on `Html`, so the compiler tries to make it work as a `String`, which also doesn't work. See the [updated scaladoc](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/a66230cbed3c3b4bf12ce2eb06081fcb51cd02c9/api/src/main/scala/play/twirl/api/Format.scala#L10-11) (`Html` is a type of `Appendable`).

> This used to support +=, but no longer is required to.
>
> @todo Change name to reflect not appendable

I guess you could combine the `String` values, then convert back to `Html`.

```
def html(htmls: Seq[Html]): Html =
    Html(htmls.foldLeft("")((r, c) => r + c.toString))

scala> val list = List(Html("<p>1</p>"), Html("<p>2</p>"), Html("<p>3</p>"))
list: List[play.twirl.api.Html] = List(<p>1</p>, <p>2</p>, <p>3</p>)

scala> html(list)
res5: play.twirl.api.Html = <p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>
```

There is actually a method called `fill` that already does this, though, in `HtmlFormat`:

```
def html(htmls: Seq[Html]): Html = HtmlFormat.fill(htmls)
```

It might be finicky a bit with `Seq`.

Comment: That's an idea. Not ideal and a strange change, but that would work.

Comment: From the scaladoc: *"This used to support +=, but no longer is required to."*

Comment: Ah I see, where does one access that documentation? I dug through the Git repository but I must have been looking through the wrong place, i couldn't find the source for Html.

Comment: @PaulSachs See the link in my edit. `Html` is in `Formats.scala`, I believe, but it extends `Appendable` (though a couple other traits).

Comment: @PaulSachs See my note about `fill` at the bottom.